# Tags as a dropdown with set tags

Tags: tags, dropdown

Sorry if this is a silly question but is it possible to have a taglist as a dropdown?

I have a page where users can post theyre own content, and I would like them to be able to choose certain tags as a dropdown, is this possible?

Heres the page so you can see
http://wordpress.art-williams.com/add-destination

I appreciate any help what so ever, anything is a huge help!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`wp_dropdown_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories) to create your dropdown:

```
wp_dropdown_categories(array('taxonomy'=> 'post_tag','hide_empty' => 0, 'name' => 'my_tags'));
```

### Update

the reason you are getting the term ID is because `wp_dropdown_categories` sets the ID's as values so instead of just echo'ing it out you need to get the term, something like:

```
$term = get_term_by('id',$your_id,'post_tag');
echo $term->name;
```

Comment: Oh wow you are a genius! :) Thank you, if I wanted to exclude a tag from that list, would I just need to put in 'exclude=ID' ?

Comment: @art: yep just add exclude with id to the array.

Comment: Ok sorry i have tried this

wp_dropdown_categories(array('taxonomy'=> 'post_tag','exclude=6', 'hide_empty' => 0, 'name' => 'my_tags'));

and it isnt working

Comment: because its wrong syntax, change`'exclude=6'` to `'exclude'=>6`

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: I dont mean to bother you, sorry but I have it working and all, so it works as a tag for the post but it shows the ID instead of the tags name. Example: http://wordpress.art-williams.com/countries/testing-dropdown-tags-8

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying

Comment: Ok sorry, erm.. in the post where the tags shows, it isn't showing the name, it is showing the id. So the tag is actually "120" instead of the name of it.

Comment: The dropdown gives the option values the term ID instead of the slug/name, which you'd get when using category as the taxonomy. For some strange reason when using a taxonomy not 'category' the function uses the term ID instead(no idea why that is).

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: Where do I put that update? it isnt working for me..

Comment: replace your code that echos the id

Comment: I'm sorry I still cant figure it out :/

Comment: I dont know what code I replacing.. where would that edit you put normaly go?